# Understanding Lattice statements from Serre's Local Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization, local-field

I am trying to understand two statements in Serre's Local Fields:

> Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over K. A lattice of V (with respect to A) is a sub-A-module X of V that is finitely generated and spans $V$

The first:

> If A is principal, this means that $X$ is a free A-module of rank $[V: K]$;

Where does the rank $[V: K]$ come from? and why is X reduced to its torsion free part?

The second:

> one can often reduce to this case by localisation, i.e., by replacing A with $A_p$ and $X$ with $A_pX$

I don't see how?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly are $A$ and $K$? Anyway, $X$ will be torsion-free as $V$ will be a torsion-free $A$-module.

Comment: $A$ is a DVR and $K =Frac(A) = A[\pi^{-1}]$. $V = \sum_{j=1}^n b_j K$ is a $K$-vector space, it is torsion free. A finitely generated sub $A$ module is contained in $\pi^{-r}\sum_{j=1}^n b_j A$ which is a free $A$ module and since $A$ is a PID any sub $A$-module is also a free $A$-module. A lattice $L\subset V$ is a full-rank one, such that $L$ is of rank $n$ and $V = \pi^{-\infty} L$

Comment: Thanks Lors Shark and reuns. Indeed $A$ is DVR (in the book it's a Dedekind domain which is stronger than DVR) and $K$ its field of fractions. if I understand correctly, $V$ is torsion-free because it is a  $K$-vector space. therefore 
 $X\subset V$ is torsion-free, otherwise $V$ won't be torsion-free. As a finitely-generated torsion-free $A$-module, $X$ is isomorphic to a sub-$A$-module (say $M$) of a free finitely-generated $A$-module. Since $A$ is PID, $M$ is also free so X is free A-module. Is that correct? @reuns I kind of followed your argument but why do you use that $X \subset A$?

Comment: DVR is stronger than Dedekind domain. DVR : only one prime/maximal ideal which is principal (so it is a PID). If $M= \sum_j A v_j$ is a finitely generated $A$-module without torsion, show by induction that $\sum_{j=1}^l A v_j = \sum_{j=1}^{d_l} Aw_j$ is free, where $d_l = \dim_{K\ vector\ space} \sum_{j=1}^l K v_j$ (try first with $A = \Bbb{Z},K = \Bbb{Q}$)